# onClick event in child component of a child page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get `onClick={props.****}` event to work in any component, whether a part of the `root` file or a child page.

As example, `handleToggleNewsletter` in the below can be called into `<Footer/>` by `onToggleNewsletter={this.handleToggleNewsletter}` as seen here...

```
class Template extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isNewsletterVisible: false,
        }
        this.handleToggleNewsletter = this.handleToggleNewsletter.bind(this)
    }

    handleToggleNewsletter() {
        this.setState({
            isNewsletterVisible: !this.state.isNewsletterVisible
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props

        return (
            <main id="app" className={`body  ${this.state.isNewsletterVisible ? 'is-newsletter-visible' : ''}`}>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    {children()}
                    <Footer onToggleNewsletter={this.handleToggleNewsletter} />
                </div>
            </main>
        )
    }
}

Template.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.func
}

export default Template
```

This then allows the `onClick={props.onToggleNewsletter}` event to be within `</Footer>` by defining the propType of `onToggleNewsletter`

```
Footer.propTypes = {
    onToggleNewsletter: PropTypes.func
}
```

**But how can I make this work when the component work in `Component` as seen in the below tree?**

```
| -- Template
| | -- {children()} (All Pages)
| | | -- Pages
| | | | -- Component - I WANT THE EVENT TO WORK HERE
| | -- Footer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `{children()}`

Let do this

```
{
  children.map(child => React.cloneElement(child, {
    onToggleNewsletter
  }))
}
```

With that, your child component will be received another prop named "onToggleNewsletter". You can use that prop and pass to grand child.

Above is an example, you must do your own to harden the code like null or empty checking, ...